# Installing elementary OS in asus zenbook flip ux360

Tags: system-installation, laptop

I am planning to buy asus zenbook flip ux360. I will be running Linux on it and would really appreciate if anyone can share their experience of running elementary OS on it. 
Here is the link to the laptop: [https://www.amazon.com/ZenBook-UX360CA-UBM1T-13-3-inch-Touchscreen-Convertible/dp/B01HZT6AR0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HZT6AR0)

**Please let me know if this question doesn't belong here and I will delete it.**

Answer (score 3):

So it's been about 2 months since I have been using elementary OS on an Asus Zenbook Flip UX360. I will write down my experience so that it helps anyone else who is planning to buy this laptop.

1. Installation:

   1. I created installation media using Rufus and it worked perfectly.
   2. Initially, I tried to install using unetbootin but it did not work.
2. After Installation

   1. Font size: Font looked tiny at first. I changed font size by using universal access menu and then choosing text size to be large. I could have also used dconf editor (org>gnome>desktop>interface)  but did not.
   2. Gesture Support:  I used [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures).
   3. Disable Bluetooth at startup: For some reason, Bluetooth gets started during startup (probably a 16.04 issue). I disabled it by adding `rfkill block bluetooth` in /etc/rc.local .
   4. Chrome zoom: I set Chrome zoom level to 125% by default (Search for zoom in Chrome settings and you will get it).
3. Experience so far

   1. It has been really good. I am in academia and this laptop is my daily driver.
   2. Touchscreen works but not sure about tablet mode. I don't use either of those, so it is not an issue.
   3. Battery life is less (about 6-7hours) than what I was getting with Windows 10 (about 9 hours). But still good enough for daily work.
   4. There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1431372) (not specific to elementary) where a process takes a lot of CPU at the start. It goes away after you touch the screen once.

I will add more things as I notice them. I think it will be good if there is a place where people can write down their experiences with different laptop models. This makes life easier for a new user who wants to buy a new laptop.